# How can I create a SQL Server 2012 database on SQL Server 2014?

Tags: sql-server

Some of our companies clients still run SQL Server 2012 but we are currently running SQL Server 2014. They want a new database in 2012. We were told that it is possible to create a new SQL Server 2012 database ON SQL Server 2014.

Is this true? And if so, can you give steps/suggestions on the best way to go about doing so?

Comment: I guess they refer to setting the compatibility level

Comment: You **cannot** - period. There's no way, no hack, no tools, no trick, no workaround to do this - you just simply **cannot**. If you create it on SQL Server 2014, it's a SQL Server 2014 database and can be used only in SQL Server 2014 (or newer) - you can never "go back" to older versions

Comment: I agree with @a_horse_with_no_name, they must be referring to setting the compatibility level at 2012.   For most intents and purposes, that would be exactly like having a 2012 Database on a 2014 server.

Comment: Thank you all. That makes absolute sense. I figured that but needed to ask anyhow. Thanks again for the clarification.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean can you create a database that can be restored in a 2012 env on a 2014 server, the answer is no.

The only way this is possible is to use some sort of ETL process to migrate the data and contents of the database, I would highly NOT recommend doing this, its a pain.